# Theming Sharepoint 2010 overwrite Corev4.css with file, do the Theme Comments work?

Tags: css, theme

I have a css file that I am using to overwrite certain areas of the corev4.css file. Will the Comments:

```
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light2-Darkest")] */
```

also be replaced in theory? I am struggling to get these Comments to change what I m asking it to change via the Site Theme area.

I changed everything to white in the Site Theme area. Then applied Dark1 to my .s4-title area to see it change the background to a color I choose, but it's not changing it. It's changing in other areas, that I don't have in my new.css file.

So does corev4.css still come into play somehow???

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Replace values that are in the Core CSS are what gets exchanged out by the theme engine. If you have any custom CSS that's overriding corev4, then that'll likely take precedence, causing it to ignore the theme engine.

In short, corev4 is absolutely in play, since that's where the theme colors get layered into the UI (theme engine manipulates corev4 at runtime).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That is what I thought was happening. Seems like the issue might be with my file not being found now...